# What is the $Ax+By+C=0$ form of the equation of the $Y$ axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to solve this problem from a Precalculus textbook : " find the locus of points $P(x,y)$ such that the distance from $P$ to the $Y$ axis is $5$" . ( Source : *Schaum's Outline Of Precalculus*).

Note : I know the answer to be found s $ x= + 5$ and $ x= -5$.

The point to straight line distance formula requires to use the $Ax+By+C=0$ form of the equation of this straight line.

I know that the " ordinary" form of the equation of the $Y$ axis : $x=0$.

I've tried to " solve " the general equation " $Ax+By+C=0$ " for $x$ and then set $x=0$.

I found $y= - \frac {C} {AB}$.

Should I substitute this value for $y$ in the point to line distance formula?

I may seem stupid, but I'm stuck.

Comment: What you've calculated is the $y$ value where your curve will intersect the $y$ axis. But you want to get all points with distance $5$ (and not distance $0$) from the $y$-axis, therefore you should set $x=\pm 5$ and calculate both $y$ values to get two points that fulfill the given condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for $y$-axis, we have $B=C=0$. Also, we can't divide by zero.

The distance formula is

$$\frac{|Ax+By+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=5$$

$$\frac{|Ax|}{|A|}=5$$

$$|x|=5$$